# Selichos for Shovavim

Tags: product-recommendation, selichot, shovavim-tat

Many sources discuss Selichos on Shovavim, but I haven't been able to find any in any of the traditional sources (Hebrewbooks.org, Sefaria, etc). Does anyone know where I can get a Selichos for Shovavim (either PDF or in print)?

Comment: Here's also one from Amsterdam: https://books.google.com/books?id=9ipmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP359 A later one from Vienna: https://books.google.com/books?id=nyZiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP918

Comment: Here's one with the South German rite from Sulzbach: https://books.google.com/books?id=sV49AAAAcAAJ&pg=PP325 , another one from Altona: https://books.google.com/books?id=Fp1EAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP360

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20298&st=&pgnum=323&hilite=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it all on the Otzar site [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=181179&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=1)

**EDIT**

You can also access it for free on the National Library of Israel [here](https://bookreader.nli.org.il/NliBookViewer/?ie_pid=IE80196146#page/n16/mode/2up).

In addition, some kehillos (congregations) include the special Selichos for Children's Illnesses as part of the service which can be accessed free from Artscroll [here](https://www.artscroll.com/images/download/Selichos-Tachluei.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Probably a dumb question, but--is there any way to download from the Otzar without signing up?

Comment: Yes - there is a print option which you can set to print as pdf which can then obviously be saved - however I think the print function may have an associated cost

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it seems to require a sign-up.